# Combine two (post) parameters in a single WordPress query

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to setup a custom WordPress query to get specific post IDs plus children of other specific posts IDs in the same query? I've tried using *post_parent__in* and *post__in* parameters but they stop working when combined.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query would help you to achieve your functionality.. Try this query to get all those posts...

```
$parent = 2;      //change as desired or get all parent post ids

$child_args = array( 
    'post_type'   => 'post', 
    'post_parent' => $parent 
);

$keys = array($parent);
$ids = array_merge($keys, array_keys( get_children( $child_args ) ));

$query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type'      => 'post', 
        'post_status'    => 'publish', 
        'post__in'       => $ids, 
        'posts_per_page' => -1 
    ) 
);
```